# Difference between big-endian and little-endian processor in example

Tags: architecture, x86, cpu-architecture

At address `1000` we have binary number:  `00000011` and at `1001` we have `00000101`.  Processor little endian read `16` bits from address `1000`. It is value `00000101 00000011=1283_10`.
However, big endian processor reads `00000011 00000101=773_10`.

Am I ok ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In little endian last byte of binary representation of the multibyte data-type is stored first.
in big endian machines, first byte of binary representation of the multibyte data-type is stored first.

I think you are right.